# How to export InDesign file to PDF with attachments as hidden pages that pop-up in new tabs

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I need to export an InDesign file to PDF with hidden pages. I know how to insert attachments into Acrobat and have new windows pop-up; and I'm wondering if there is a way to do this from InDesign directly.